# R - Statistics - How to know if two pairs of value are significantly different from two datasets ( = outliers of a correlation)

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, outliers

First of all, sorry for the title. Since I'm a real noob about statistics, it was pretty complicated to know how to express my issue...

That said, I'll try to be as clear as possible. Thank you for your patience !
Here is an example data :

```
dput(test)
structure(list(coords = c("chr11:71478469-71480755", "chr11:72233163-72233655", 
"chr11:72237796-72238263", "chr11:72688537-72692753", "chr11:72688537-72693325", 
"chr11:73390921-73392211"), dPSI.BM_PrePB = c(-0.211854387676934, 
0.291806579364004, 0.333357771512903, -0.314633537078126, 0.27350910457179, 
0.263596043484295), dPSI.BM_Bact = c(-0.326793349890209, 0.287308483987104, 
0.332897018970844, 0.225803052051341, -0.226736267092175, 0.262209354876416
)), row.names = 825:830, class = "data.frame")
```

My full data has about 4400 rows.

So I needed to know if two datasets were correlated (column dPSI.BM_PrePB and dPSI.BM_Bact of my example data). Here are the summaries of my 2 true datasets.

```
 summary(mergeboth$dPSI.BM_PrePB)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.94914 -0.32776  0.21163  0.01302  0.31650  0.94582

 summary(mergeboth$dPSI.BM_Bact)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.96366 -0.32977  0.21163  0.01103  0.31833  0.95622
```

I did a pearson correlation and it was pretty clear that my two datasets are correlated I also visualized it with a scatterplot :
[Scatterplot of pearson correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fJyn.png)

Now my problem is : I NEED to extract the few 'outliers' (looks like it is way less than 100 out of my 4400) because it has a biological impact in another study. I was thinking of a way to compare pairs of value in order to get the ones that are significantly different but I can't wrap my mind around it. I just simply don't know how to do it.
I also saw in many topics that retrieve the outliers is complicated (and could involved to set a threshold for example) so I can't start from the correlation analysis right ?
I know that we can test the mean of two populations but I'm not interesting in the mean, I'm interesting in the precise value that are significantly not following the same behavior as the others events.

Thanks a lot in advance for your suggestions.
Have a nice day ! :)

Elsa

Comment: `cooks.distance` will give you leverage points of a regression. But this question seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code. Maybe post to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will explore this. :)